# How to indent the graphics caption

Tags: captions, indentation, koma-script

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX with the document class `scrreprt`.
My problem is that I include a graphic whose description starts at the left side of the page, which is usually nice, but in my case I have an `itemize` and `description` environment where the text already has a big gap towards the left border.
I want the description of the graphic to be indented too.
This options should not be set globally but only for this one picture.

```
\begin{description}
\item[I) ] bla
\item[II) ] bla
  \begin{itemize}
    \item bla
    \item bla
      \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.88\textwidth]{bla.pdf}
    \captionof{figure}[bla]{this text should show up further to the right}
    \label{fig:bla}
      \end{center}
\item[III) ]
\end{itemize}
\end{description}
```

Comment: Compiling your code leaves the expected result: The left margin of both the graphic + the caption is intended to the current list level, and from there the contents is centered on the page. To me this sounds exactly what you want. Is this not so? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Werner: If I compile this code snipped with the same document preamble like in my answer below, I get a wrong centering of the caption, it's not centered unter the graphic.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: That's correct. I compiled it using [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com) that runs TeX Live 2009. Under that distribution, merely adding the (your) [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to the preamble centers the caption.

Comment: @Werner: I just tried it with ScribTeX and did not get a perfectly centered caption, either. (Tried it w/ and w/o caption package.) That's strange...

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: On ScribTeX with preamble `\documentclass{scrreprt}\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}\begin{document}...\end{document}` = incorrect caption alignment; with preamble `\documentclass{scrreprt}\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}\usepackage{caption}\begin{document}...\end{document}` = correct alignment. Strange for sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\setcapmargin` locally, such as

```
\includegraphics[width=0.88\textwidth]{bla.pdf}
\setcapmargin[4cm]{1cm}
\captionof{figure}[bla]{this text should show up further to the right}
```

- `\setcapmargin[left margin]{margin}` defines a margin and optionally different left margin for captions
- `\setcapmargin*[inner margin]{margin}` defines a margin and optionally different inner margin for captions, useful for two-sided layout

For the left margin you could use the indentation length command of the environment you would like to match.

These are KOMA-Script commands, you can use them because you use scrreprt. The `caption` package provides similar features.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the figure in a minipage to get a proper alignment of the caption, for example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[I) ] bla
\item[II) ] bla
  \begin{itemize}
    \item bla
    \item bla
      \par\begin{minipage}{0.88\textwidth} % better replace 0.88\textwidth with \linewidth
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bla.pdf}
        \captionof{figure}[bla]{this text should show up further to the right}
        \label{fig:bla}
      \end{minipage}
\item[III) ]
\end{itemize}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of guessing the `.88\textwidth`, `\linewidth` should be used for the width of the `minipage`.

Comment: I just have copied the `0.88\textwidth` from the code snipped given by the questioner. But (of course) you are right, `\linewidth` would have been a much better choice. I added this to my answer as a comment.